# IIS7 Authentication on Server 2008

Tags: iis, iis-7

I recently upgraded my Server 2000 running IIS6 to Server 2008 running IIS7.  Servers are stand alone, no A/D. I have a website designed with Frontpage 2003 running Server Extensions 2003 which I also migrated to my new Server 2008. Site on old server required username and password which I set up to allow access by disabling annonomous access.  How do I do the same thing with IIS7 on Server 2008?  I prefer to use Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In the site's Authentication settings, disable anonymous and enable integrated windows authentication.